# The proof of convergence

Tags: matrices, optimization

I am reading the Boris's book **Introduction to optimization**. How to prove the following Theorem 2 in Section 2.1.2?

> **Theorem**: Given the process $x^{k+1}=x^k-\gamma(Ax^k+\phi(x^k))$. Let the matrix $-A$ be stable and let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy the condition
>   $$||\phi(x)|| \le L ||x||$$
>   Then, if
>   $$L < \frac{1}{2||U||}, 0<\gamma<\frac{||U||^{-1}-2L}{(L+||A||)^2},$$
>   where matrix $U$ is the solution of the matrix equation
>   $$UA + A^TU=I,$$
>   the process converges to zero with the rate of geometric progression for any $x^0$:
>   $$||x^k||^2\le ||x^0||^2||U^{-1}||||U||q^k$$
>   $$q=1-\frac{1}{2}\gamma||U||^{-1} + \gamma L + \frac{1}{2}\gamma^2(||A||+L)^2.$$

The statements above are the contents of theorem. For the proof, there is a hint in the book:

> It suffices to introduce $u_k = (Ux^k,x^k)$ and derive the relation $u_{k+1}\le q u_k$.

How can we prove the theorem is true?

I have verified that when $u_{k+1}\le q u_k$ holds, the convergence can be guaranteed as the Theorem states. Thus, the remaining work is to show that $u_{k+1}\le q u_k$.
\begin{align}
u_{k+1} &= (Ux^{k+1},x^{k+1}) \\&= (Ux^k-\gamma U(Ax^k+\phi(x^k)),x^k-\gamma(Ax^k+\phi(x^k))\\
&=(Ux^k,x^k)-(Ux^k,\gamma(Ax^k+\phi(x^k)))-(\gamma U(Ax^k+\phi(x^k)),x^k)+(\gamma U(Ax^k+\phi(x^k)),\gamma (Ax^k+\phi(x^k)))
\end{align}
Then, I stuck here. Because I do not know how to establish the relation between the equation above with $u_k$, i.e., $(Ux^k,x^k)$. For example, there is something like $(Ux^k,Ax^k)$, and how can we compare its value with $(Ux^k,x^k)$?

Comment: I do not know how this theorem can be true.

Comment: It would be better to include what you have tried so far and where you're stuck. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).